# Problem pulling images from high res folder

Tags: android, drawable

I have 3 drawable folders in my res folder.  drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-hdpi.  I have low, medium, and high res images for these respective folders.

I've been testing my application on a Samsung Moment, which is an mdpi screen.  Today, I went to test my application on a Samsung Epic (480x800), which is a hdpi screen.  Unfortunately, the images my application is using are incorrectly pulled from the drawable-mdpi screen and not the drawable-hdpi.

Does anyone know why?

The images in both folders are named the same.  Also, in my manifest, I have the following tag:

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />
```

I'm not quite sure why it wouldn't be pulling the images from the drawable-hdpi folder.

Comment: So because the density is the same (?) it's still pulling the medium resolution images?  Hrm...  I don't like this... my buttons look really tiny on the Samsung Epic.  What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read up a bit on the subject, and I think you dont grasp the way screen auto adjustment works, I belive you can just eliminate that whole section from the manifest and it should work based on what I read are the default values, though i might be wrong about this.

Taken from here: [Manifest attributes for screens support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#attrs)

> In general, when you declare a screen-size attribute (smallScreens, normalScreens, largeScreens, or xlargeScreens) as "true", you are signaling to the platform that your application is designed to render properly on that screen size. As a result, the platform does not apply any size-compatibility features (such as a virtual HVGA display area). If you declare a screen-size attribute as "false", you are signaling that your application is not designed for that screen size. In this case, the platform does apply size-compatibility features, rendering the application in an HVGA baseline display area. If the current screen is larger than normal size, the platform renders the application in a virtual HVGA screen on the larger screen.

Do read up on the link I posted, it should provide a clearer picture, as it has a couple of examples.